# error: Entity class must be annotated with @Entity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I decided to use kotlin with Room library and I really faced a lot of problems and tired from reading reference and finding a solution 
My Data Class:

```
@Entity
data class HistorySong(
        @PrimaryKey
        var SongId: Int =0,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "song_name")
        var songName: String="",

        @ColumnInfo(name = "song_artist")
        var songArtist: String="",

        @ColumnInfo(name = "song_link")
        var songLink: String="",

        @ColumnInfo(name = "image_path")
        var songImagePath: String="",

        @ColumnInfo(name="is_favoutire")
        var songisFavourite: Boolean= false
)
```

My Dao class :

```
@Dao
 interface HistorySongDao {

       @Delete
       fun deleteSong(historySongDao: HistorySongDao)

       @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        fun insert(vararg historySongDao: HistorySongDao)

       @Query("SELECT * FROM HistorySong")
        fun loadAllSongs(): Array<HistorySong>


       @Query("SELECT * FROM HistorySong WHERE songId = :mId")
        fun findById(mId: Int): HistorySong

       @Query("SELECT * FROM HistorySong WHERE is_favoutire = :getFavourite ")
        fun getFavourite(getFavourite : Boolean) : Array<HistorySong>



       @Update
       fun updateUsers(vararg historySong: HistorySong)
}
```

Database Class:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(QueuedSong::class, HistorySongDao::class), version = 2)
abstract class AppDataBase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun queuedSongDao(): QueuedSongDao
    abstract fun historySongDao(): HistorySongDao
}
```

QueuedSong is working great but the problem in  historySong is:

```
e: F:\SmartStreamer\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\pro\smartstreamer\Database\QueuedDatabase\HistorySongDao.java:7: error: Entity class must be annotated with @Entity
public abstract interface HistorySongDao {
                ^
w: F:\SmartStreamer\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\pro\smartstreamer\Database\QueuedDatabase\AppDataBase.java:10: warning: Room cannot create an SQLite connection to verify the queries. Query verification will be disabled. Error: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax error)
public abstract class AppDataBase extends android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase {
                ^
w: F:\SmartStreamer\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\pro\smartstreamer\Database\QueuedDatabase\HistorySong.java:10: warning: There are multiple good constructors and Room will pick the no-arg constructor. You can use the @Ignore annotation to eliminate unwanted constructors.
public final class HistorySong {
             ^
e: F:\SmartStreamer\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\pro\smartstreamer\Database\QueuedDatabase\HistorySongDao.java:15: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    com.pro.smartstreamer.Database.QueuedDatabase.HistorySongDao... historySongDao);
                                                                    ^
e: F:\SmartStreamer\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\pro\smartstreamer\Database\QueuedDatabase\HistorySongDao.java:11: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    com.pro.smartstreamer.Database.QueuedDatabase.HistorySongDao historySongDao);
                                                                 ^
e: F:\SmartStreamer\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\pro\smartstreamer\Database\QueuedDatabase\HistorySongDao.java:30: error: com.pro.smartstreamer.Database.QueuedDatabase.HistorySongDao is part of com.pro.smartstreamer.Database.QueuedDatabase.AppDataBase but this entity is not in the database. Maybe you forgot to add com.pro.smartstreamer.Database.QueuedDatabase.HistorySong to the entities section of the @Database?
    public abstract void updateUsers(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

and :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I really can't find a solution.. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: For starters, you're trying to insert and delete `HistorySongDao` objects instead of `HistorySong` objects. See if fixing that helps with some of these errors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As it said in the first comment, you are trying to insert and delete HistorySongDao objects instead of HistorySong, your code will become:

```
@Dao
 interface HistorySongDao {

       @Delete
       fun deleteSong(vararg historySong: HistorySong)

       @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        fun insert(vararg historySong: HistorySong)

       @Query("SELECT * FROM HistorySong")
        fun loadAllSongs(): Array<HistorySong>

       @Query("SELECT * FROM HistorySong WHERE songId = :mId")
        fun findById(mId: Int): HistorySong

       @Query("SELECT * FROM HistorySong WHERE is_favoutire = :getFavourite ")
        fun getFavourite(getFavourite : Boolean) : Array<HistorySong>

       @Update
       fun updateUsers(vararg historySong: HistorySong)
}
```

Answer (score 85):

I solved it by changing my @Database's argument (RoomDatabase class), I didn't realize and put my DAO where should be my Entity.

In my case:

```
@Database(entities = [WordDao::class],version = 1)
```

changed to:

```
@Database(entities = [WordEntity::class],version = 1)
```

So, when somebody gets this error, maybe should to check not only where the entity is declared but too where it is used.

Comment: Thanks from 2024 back to you in 2019!  I spent an hour on this and looked and looked and looked. I have several entities and they all worked, but not my latest addition. Thanks to you I immediately spotted I'd inadvertently added "Dao" to the end of the new class name. So easy to miss. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Update Database Class to this

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(QueuedSong::class, HistorySong::class), version = 2)
abstract class AppDataBase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun queuedSongDao(): QueuedSongDao
abstract fun historySongDao(): HistorySongDao
}
```

I change HistorySongDao.class to HistorySong.class

Answer (score 7):

You have mistaken in your Database class with entities.
Maybe you are calling Dao Interface rather then Entity class.

Comment: Can you tell the class names in your answer. It will be more helpful for understanding.

Comment: Open your Database class right here.. @Database (entities ={Entity.class}, version=1,exportedSchema =false) > look at the the entities={ } part here maybe you are calling your Dao interface or something else.

Answer (score 3):

By me it was a different problem: [ instead of {

I put :

```
@Database(entities = [Sensor.class, Meter.class],version = 2)
```

instead of:

```
@Database(entities ={Sensor.class, Meter.class}, version = 2)
```